# Code Igniter Auto Load With custom name

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoloader

i want to know is there way that  I can pass my custom class name in autoload class

Example:
       in a controller i know we can do this

```
$this->load->library('parser','','my_parser')
```

but what i want to know is there way that i can pass custom name while autoloading

i.e

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(('database','','my_db'));
```

how can i achieve this  ?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible without replacing class `CI_Loader`, see how to replacing core class: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/core_classes.html , what you have to do is create same class `CI_Loader` with edit in this function : `_ci_autoloader` https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L1169

Comment: Thanks for the help. well i wont be changing core classes yet as i am still relatively new to CI  :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'session','custom_library');
```

I had a custom helper class in one of my project and load automatically by adding it to the autoload configuration file like this way

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('new_helper');
```

but never tried with library,you can try above way this may help you.

**Note**: The Database classes can not be extended or replaced with your own classes. All other classes are able to be replaced/extended.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: this wasn't the question :( i don't want to load extra classes
all i want to do is load database class with any custom name

Comment: Note: The Database classes can not be extended or replaced with your own classes. All other classes are able to be replaced/extended.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: so what u mean is we are forced to use "$this->db" and can't have our own custom name instead of db  for example "$this->my_db"

Comment: May be but not sure,I have to look it

Comment: Well Thanks anyways :)